# 'Throwing warnings' from my code

Tags: c#, warnings

I am writing a tool that processes some files. This tool will have a command-line interface but can also be used as a class library from third-party code. To deal with an error, I just throw an exception. Third-party code can handle the exception, and the command-line interface might just print it and abort. However, apart from fatal errors, it is also possible that a situation arises that is not fatal and the process can continue, for which I would like to 'throw a warning' and continue.

*How do I deal with warnings*, in such way that both third-party code and the command-line interface can do something with it?

Comment: It's frustrating that C#/.NET doesn't have a conventional system for raising warnings like exists in other languages. In Python I can do `warnings.warn('some message')` or `logging.warning('some message')` and know that my message is likely to be visible to calling code and that its authors can globally configure how warnings are handled and logged. In C#, there isn't an analogous system. You've got no idea what logging library, if any, the calling application is using, and probably couldn't hook into it if you did. What's left? Just *print* the warning and hope that doesn't break anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You throw an exception for this as well (assuming the error condition is indeed exceptional - that is expected to be rare).

Exceptions are not always lethal - you need to throw a specific *type* of exception that the third party code and command line code can catch and act on.

One rule of exception handling is to handle exceptions you know how to handle - if you have a specific exception type for the error and you document it, client code should know how to deal with it (or not).

---

If what you are trying to do is provide *information* to using code - warnings that are handled within your library already but that the users may want to know - you can output traces using the [tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx) subsystem. All users will need to do is configure a listener and will be able to get the information during runtime.

Comment: I think that warning usually means that the normal result should be returned, but it also should have a warning attached, somehow. But if you use exception, you can't return a value at the same time.

Comment: @svick - Sure you can - with a custom exception class, you can add whatever additional properties you wish. And [`Exception`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx) itself has a `Data` KVP property for this.

Comment: @Oded Apologies. I misinterpreted your comments.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you not to throw an exception, they should be avoided if possible (they are resources costly). Instead you can create an event and raise it. Third party code and command-line interface will just need to sign to this event.

Comment: Good advice.  Googlers: if you're thinking "a stack trace would be useful for this warning", just use an exception. The exception system is essentially a highly-instrumented, expensive event system. If the warning is rare (*and the error is recoverable!*), probably use a [custom `Exception`.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229064%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  Also, don't extend `WarningException`, as it extends `SystemException`, and that's [reserved by convention.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229007(v=vs.100).aspx)