# Is warnings as expesinve as exceptions?

Tags: c#, exception, warnings

Supose that I am adding data in a database, some value is unique, so one user can try to add but a second user added it before first user finished.

In this case, I would like to warning the client that the value is added, because I don't considerate this an error, just a help to the user to know why it couldn't add the value. For that, I was  thinking to use warnings instead of exceptions.

I was thinking in warnings because exceptions are expensive, but i don't know if a warning is a kind of exception or not or if it less expensive. Because I know that one reason because of an expcetion it is cost it is because of the track trace, but I don't know if a warning has this cost.

In this post ['Throwing warnings' from my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439811/throwing-warnings-from-my-code) someone tells that an options it is create an event and rise it, but I am not sure if this makes the code more complex really only to warning something.

Another option that I was thinking, the method could return a tuple, one value is the result, the second value the warning message, so if  this warning message is empty, then it means there is no warnings, but if it has a message, then it is a warning that the user should to know. But in this case I don't know if it s a good idea return a warning as result of the method.

Thanks.

Comment: exceptions aren't *that* expensive, unless you're in a critical IO loop; they only *look* expensive in the debugger because the debugger does a lot of things when they are caught; I very much doubt that exception cost will be relevant if you're talking about data conflicts - the main time you'd avoid them is in things like `int.Parse` (vs `int.TryParse`) in code that is, say, reading a 500k row, 40 column CSV of integers (or dealing with socket IO, etc)